# charAt in method not working

Tags: java, methods

here is the method:

```
    public static String getEncrypted(String x){
    char y;
    String output = " ";
    int count = 0, position = 0, place= 0;
    int length = x.length();
    while(count < length){
        place = length - position;
        y = x.charAt(place);
        position++;
        count++;
        output = output + y;
    }
    return output;
}
```

I am able to compile the code which basically takes a string splits it up into the words that make it then feeds it to this method.

When I use the program and enter something to be used by this method I get the error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at encrypt.getEncrypted(encrypt.java:37)
    at encrypt.main(encrypt.java:23)
```

My question is what I am doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: place is zero based but length - position is not. you should do length - position - 1. That way when length is 4, place can be 3 at the maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `place = length - position;` to `place = length - position - 1`; and try again

Comment: That worked. Thank you. Why did that fix the error? if length is 8 and position is 0 Shouldn't length - position = 8 and then it gets the last char?

Comment: The last character would be at place 7 not 8 because place starts with 0.

Comment: @TheTwistyTie Indices start counting from 0, so the first char is at position 0, the second at position 1, etc., and the last char at position (length - 1).

Comment: Ahhh that makes sense. I should have thought of that. I keep trying to accept the answer and it doesn't let me. It gives me a count down to when I can. I'll accept that when it is over.